# file() produces different output if file name contains unicode characters?

Tags: r, unicode, zip, filenames

I'm trying to understand an inconsistency in the behaviour of `R`'s `file()` function.

Example:

```
# openssl for producing hash values
require(openssl)

# sample data
data(mtcars)
saveRDS(mtcars, './mtcars.rds')
saveRDS(mtcars, './mtcars测试.rds')

# if file name is ascii, file() produces different outputs
# for raw = FALSE/TRUE
sha2(file('./mtcars.rds', raw = FALSE), size = 256L)
sha2(file('./mtcars.rds', raw = TRUE), size = 256L)

# if file name contains unicode characters,
# the output stays the same regardless of raw = FALSE/TRUE
sha2(file('./mtcars测试.rds', raw = FALSE), size = 256L)
sha2(file('./mtcars测试.rds', raw = TRUE), size = 256L)

# But text files are not affected
writeLines(text = 'openssl, mtcars, 天地玄黄', con = './mtcars.txt')
writeLines(text = 'openssl, mtcars, 天地玄黄', con = './mtcars测试.txt')

sha2(file('./mtcars.txt', raw = FALSE), size = 256L)
sha2(file('./mtcars.txt', raw = TRUE), size = 256L)

sha2(file('./mtcars测试.txt', raw = FALSE), size = 256L)
sha2(file('./mtcars测试.txt', raw = TRUE), size = 256L)
```

I tested the above on both Windows (`R` 3.3.3 x64) and CentOS (`R` 3.4.0 x64), with `openssl` version 0.9.6.

My question is, **why** is this happening?

My best guess so far:

- `file()` uses special method if given a `zip` file. (And I know `RDS` is a `R` object gzipped to the disk.)
- Some low level function of `R` still don't like Unicode characters in file names.
- A file name containing Unicode characters blinds the `zip` file detection and forces `file()` to use `raw = TRUE`.